# Populating a set of checkboxes based on a file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binary, bitarray

I'm trying to figure out how to read a file (not created by my program), using a `BinaryReader`, and checking or unchecking a set of checkboxes accordingly.

I've managed to figure out that the checkboxes are stored as such:

```
Checkbox 1 = 00 01
Checkbox 2 = 00 02
Checkbox 3 = 00 04
Checkbox 4 = 00 08
Checkbox 5 = 00 10
Checkbox 6 = 00 20
Checkbox 7 = 00 40
Checkbox 8 = 00 60
Checkbox 9 = 00 80
Checkbox 10 = 01 00
Checkbox 11 = 02 00
etc
```

So if, in the file, checkboxes 1, 2, 6, and 10 where checked the hex value would be: 01 23. How would I break this down so that the correct checkboxes in program would be checked?

Answer (score 2):

Keep a `CheckBox[]` or `List<CheckBox>` with the `CheckBox` references in the correct order so that you can refer to them by index. You would loop through the individual bit values and use a counter to keep track of the index associated with that bit:

```
short setBits = 0x0123; # short because it is 2 bytes.
short currentBit = 0x0001;
// loop through the indexes (assuming 16 CheckBoxes or fewer)
for (int index = 0; index < checkBoxes.Length; index++) {
    checkBoxes[index].Checked = (setBits & currentBit) == currentBit;
    currentBit <<= 1; // shift one bit left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a typo in your example. Checkbox 8 should not be 0060, but rather 0080. So 123 would mean bits: 1, 2, 6, 9 (not 10).

Like this:

```
Checkbox 01 = 00 01
Checkbox 02 = 00 02
Checkbox 03 = 00 04
Checkbox 04 = 00 08
Checkbox 05 = 00 10
Checkbox 06 = 00 20
Checkbox 07 = 00 40
Checkbox 08 = 00 80
Checkbox 09 = 01 00
Checkbox 10 = 02 00
```

To check what check box is set you could use code like this:

```
// var intMask = Convert.ToInt32("0123", 16); // use this line if your input is string
var intMask = 0x0123";
var bitArray = new BitArray(new[] { intMask });
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    var isCheckBoxSet = bitArray.Get(i);
    if (isCheckBoxSet)
        Console.WriteLine("Checkbox {0} is set", i + 1);
}
```

The output:

```
Checkbox 1 is set
Checkbox 2 is set
Checkbox 6 is set
Checkbox 9 is set
```

So your code with checkboxes would be as simple as this:

```
var checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();
var intMask = 0x0123;
var bitArray = new BitArray(new[] { intMask });
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    checkboxes.Add(new CheckBox { Checked = bitArray.Get(i) });
```

Comment: +1 for `BitArray`. I must be too comfortable with bit-twiddling. I'd rather use `BitArray` myself depending on who else might be maintaining the code.

Answer (score 0):

This'd be adequate - adjust the upper limit appropriately.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    Checkbox[i + 1].Checked = (yourbits && (1 << i)) != 0
}
```